# Is there a reliable way to stop a thread without using Cancel?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

My scenario seems to be the opposite of what most people need.  I do not need to block a thread, and I do not see a good way to "cooperatively cancel" the thing.

I have a `UserControl` with a grid control on it.  That grid's selection is used to inform a detail panel on the same `UserControl`.  As the user selects rows, there is an `async` fetch of related records going on.  Sometimes, that fetch takes longer than it takes for the user to select a different row, causing the threaded fetch for that new row.  This repeats as the user moves from row to row in the grid.  It is possible for them to use the arrow keys, for instance, so they can move from row-to-row rather rapidly.

I cannot block the thread because I need the currently selected row's data to be fetched.  Rather, I need an effective way to instantly stop the previous attempt(s).  Otherwise, these fetches pile up and I sometimes even end up with `OutOfMemoryExceptions` if the related data is sizable enough.

Here's the basic idea and an example:

The user clicks the grid row, and the bound property fires off a method that fetches the detail data, and that includes the fetch call for related items:

```
private ObservableCollection<DataRecord> _currentData = null;
public ObservableCollection<DataRecord> CurrentData
{
    get => _currentData;
    set => SetProperty(ref _currentData, value, () => CurrentData);
}

public DataRecord SelectedRecord
{
    get => _selectedRecord;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedRecord, value, () => SelectedRecord);
        FetchDataAsync();
    }
}

public async void FetchDataAsync()
{
    CurrentData?.Clear();
    var dataList = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => GetDataList());
    CurrentData = dataList.ToObservableCollection();
}

private List<DataRecord> GetDataList()
{
    var dataList = new List<DataRecord>();
    using (var context = new DataContext(new DbFactory().GetConnectionString()))
        dataList = context.MyDataTable.Where(x => x.ID == SelectedRecord.ID).ToList();
    return dataList;
}
```

The only line that does any real work in the `GetDataList()` method is the fetch from the database, so there is no good place to look for a Cancel flag.

I wonder if my use of a common collection as the ultimate destination for these returned record sets is part of the problem?

Comment: Make the request async all the way down and pass a `CancellationToken` along with it. Cancel the token when the user changes their selection.

Comment: The reliable way is to use a CancellationToke. `async void` should never be used, except for event handlers though, which means that `FetchDataAsync` has a bad bug. `async void` can't be awaited, the runtime knows nothing about those tasks and by the time they run, the objects they try to access may already be disposed

Comment: Stop usings linq's loops and make your own, then you got plenty of places to cancel. Literally once per itteration.

Comment: What ORM are you using? EF has ToListAsync which means makes both Task.Run and `GetDataList()` aren't needed. You don't need `ToObservableCollection` to set a property and raise the notification event either. `ObservableCollection` is only needed when you want to *modify* the collection

Comment: You could use just `CurrentData=await contex...ToListAsync()` to load the data and set the property. ToListAsync accepts a CancellationToken, which means you you can cancel it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have seen the advice against the `void` return before, but in this case, what alternative makes any sense?  There's nothing to return.  And I am going to try that `ToListAsync()` option.

Comment: `async Task`. That's explained in all those advices. `async Task` is the signature of an async method that doesn't return anything. As for `Otherwise, these fetches pile up` the answer here is to *not* load items after each selection. Load them just once. You shouldn't even have to do that if you use an ORM, it should load any related *entities* automatically, based on the configured relations

Comment: If you have a lot of data the solution is to only load what's going to be displayed, using data virtualization. Another thing to consider is *debouncing* - don't even start loading if the selection changes too quickly. You can use Reactive Extensions for this, or the Ix.NET which handles UI events specifically

Comment: PS: WPF has delayed binding. Perhaps all you need to do is add `Delay` to your binding. Check [Rick Strahl's article on Debouncing](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jul/02/debouncing-and-throttling-dispatcher-events) which also mentions `Text="{Binding TopicsFilter,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Delay=500}"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "instantly stop" and operation that doesn't support being instantly stopped or cancelled. Your `GetDataList()` method doesn't. Once it has been called, it will run until it either completes or throws an exception.

Also, property setters should not kick off asynchronous operations: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

What you can do here is to handle the `PropertyChanged` event for the `SelectedRecord` property, cancel any task that is currently executing and start another one.

When the task completes, you need to determine whether the results are still accurate or if a new selection has been made since the task was started. If the latter, you could just throw away the results and wait for the last one.

Another option to handle this would be to use a library like [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) that supports reactive and composable properties.